# What databases let you do ops on data?

Tags: database

I like redis. It has strings, list, sets and more. I looked up couchdb thinking its similar but it isn't. Redis allows me to do ops on the data like incr, push/pop list, get list items from ? to ?, etc.

What other databases allow me to do operations like that on data?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of MongoDB, it supports atomic operations like inc,push,set,unset etc. on the data. A complete list is given at: [www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) 
Next release (v2.2) of MongoDB has aggregation framework built into it, then you can do operations like: avg, more info at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/